# Get ajax post with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I don't understand why this is not working.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'test.php',
  data: {name: 'Wayne', age: 27},
});

echo $_POST['name']; echo $_POST['age'];
```

It outputs the following.

[image: Picture Header]

[image: Picture with Header]

Comment: We need more information, screenshot or code from your `test.php` file

Comment: Ajax runs on the client-side and is assynchonous... The PHP just can't have the POST values before the page is displayed on the client-side and the request is made.

Comment: I showed you all the code which i have used

Comment: You don't even use the request result... Look for examples using the `success` callback. You have a bit more reading to do about ajax... I suggest you [this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I want to get the post data with php, what should a success made with javascript help me in here? As showed on the picture there is a response from the ajax

Comment: Nope... What I see are PHP error message about undefined "indexes" of `$_POST` array on page load... Then an ajax request occurs from client-side... but you do nothing with the result.

Comment: Yea the error message apears because it can't find the post data, because it probably selects the first header, instead of the second one

Comment: On page load, there is no POST values... I think you agree. Then the page is sent to the client-side (wich is the user's browser)... The PHP has finished processing from here. Then the Ajax resquest is triggered... And there possibly is a result, but, again, you don't use it.

Comment: Okay maybe i just don't understand what you mean. Could you please show me how I can get the post data with php?

Comment: Your screenshot appears to show the result of accessing the `test.php` script directly in the browser. Entering a URL in a browser means the browser is making a `GET` request, not `POST`, so those notices are expected. But if you load a webpage with your jQuery snippet inside it, that will indeed make a `POST` request to `test.php`, and it will echo this values. In order to actually see this, as others have said, you need to do something with the Ajax result, by adding a `success` callback. If this is just to `console.log` the response, you should see the name and age you submitted.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work and IMO the "best" way to do this is to use two different files.

1. One file ( index.html / index.php ) from where you make the Ajax request and
2. one file ( eg. backend.php ) where a response is sent back

The **reason why it will not work with one file**, is because the PHP is ran before the request is made ( when the index.something file is rendered ).

Since you are expecting an immediate feedback from the Ajax request, you need to have a success function which does something with the data returned from backend.php.

The **flow** is like:

1. index.html makes request to backend.php and awaits a response
2. backend responds
3. index.html receives backend.php response in the success function

### Example:

#### index.html ( first file )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
        function $ajaxReq() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "backend.php",
                data: {
                    name: "John",
                    age: 23
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="$ajaxReq()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

#### backend.php ( second file )

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    echo "Hello, my name is " . $name . " and I am " . $age . " years old.";
?>
```

Comment: Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: 'test.php',
 data: {name: 'Wayne', age: 27},
})
```

instead of

```
type: "POST"
```

as shown here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I just made it like in this tutorial displayed: http://thisinterestsme.com/simple-ajax-request-example-jquery-php/

Comment: `type` is an alias for `method`... That ain't the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as a basic test...

```
<?php
if($_POST){
  echo $_POST['name']."<br>";

  if($_POST['age']<21){
    echo "Too young to log in!";
  }else{
    echo $_POST['age']." years old is ok!";
  }

}else{
  echo "No post values yet.";
  ?>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {name: 'Wayne', age: 19},
    success: function(response){
      $("#result").html("I'm the Ajax result!<br><br>"+response);
    }
  });
  </script>
  <?php
}
?>
```

You should notice that the PHP is ran twice here... On load and then on Ajax request.

Comment: it displays: No post values yet.

Comment: Sorry... I missed the `#` in `("#result").html(...)` -- Retry.

Comment: It outputs the data and reloads the page infinitie times

Comment: lol... Sure.... Usually, you will run an Ajax from page A to get some content from ressource B. That anwer is just an example about the timing implied with Ajax (milliseconds).

Comment: I modified it to avoid the infinite looping. ;)

Comment: I want to make a dropdown and when I select something it should display the current value, but it should be displayed with php not javascript. Is this even possible when you can just load data from other ressources?

Comment: with the current code  it displays again: No post values yet.

Comment: mmm... That is so theorical that I keep on messing lol. With was is there now, it should display both messages... With some milliseconds for the data to be displayed.

Comment: Ok, now you have to explain why the `select` value has to be displayed by PHP. There is certainly a solution to what you intend to do... We just have to take it from the right end. ;)

Comment: I want to use it in oop. It depends on the dropdown which data will be displayed. But I am only starting with javascript and these stuff, so I want to make as much as possible with php.

Comment: And what is the problem to display the `select` value using JS/jQuery **and** also send the that value to server to do whatever you have to ?

Comment: because it would maybe be less code with php. I just would need the post value to be displayed

Comment: The question here... Isn't about more/less code. It's about the logical steps to get and process user interaction. You have to code the logic taking delays in account. So if user selects an option, you can *instantly* confirm that choice using JS... While you send it to PHP for processing. There are delays with Ajax for the response to come back (milliseconds). But you can use that response to act on what was *instantly* done on JS side, if needed! If everything is ok at this point... (as it normally should) Well that's easy...

Comment: And I would add that it's important to have your page in one file.... And the ressource used to process the user inputs in another.

Comment: The ajax post return has to be displayed in a php function, because there will be other paramaters to

Comment: Okay, then you send the data and *instantly* display it... Then, milliconds after, you display the additional param from the Ajax response.

Comment: Is there no chance to get the ajax data with a $_POST['dataName']? these milliseconds are not that important to me :)

Comment: Ajax is initiated from JS/jQuery on client side... It asks a PHP ressource to reply based on some collected data. I think that is the part you still do not get.

Comment: Look... I edited again to show you a *basic* additionnal info from the server, based on the data sent. --- So you can display the name and age submitted... And wait for the approval from server.

Comment: I can't follow this conversation anymore, I am sorry :/ I just want to get the the selected option of a select to be stored in a php variable without a refresh of the current page. Please don't say i don't get it, just say yes or no.

Comment: YES. You can send a selected option back to PHP. The concept about *"storing"* it is wrong... Since PHP take about less than a second to execute and dies right after. That isn't a *store*. You have to use the value to send something back to the browser. If you want to store the age in memory, on server side, look for `$_SESSION`. But that would be another thing we just did not discussed.

Comment: Ahhhh after some testing of your code I understand now what you mean. I am more interested in storing the data, I will give it a try with $_SESSION. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy coding ;)